# Как реализовать такой эффект загрузки?

Tags: android

Скажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой эффект загрузки? Где все блестит (не знаю как это назвать), а когда контент загружается там появляются данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такой эффект насколько я знаю называется ShimmerEffect и впервые был реализован Facebook. У себя в проекте я использую [данную библиотеку](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/). Для начала нужно подключить ее в градле:

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0@aar'
```

дальше после успешного импорта можно ее использовать. Переходим в нужный макет :

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/polls_container_view"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
shimmer:duration="100">



</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

внутрь ложим то что должно переливаться. Вот есть [статья](https://medium.com/@howtodoandroid/shimmer-effect-for-android-recyclerview-example-a9315b46cdc0) по данному вопросу где тоже рассмотрены примеры реализации данного эффекта. Для запуска и остановки можно использовать такую комманду:

```
shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer()
shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer()
```